# how to delegate change select2

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using select2 and I've used this code

```
        $("select").on("select2:select", function(e) {
```

but it works just once and I want to select many times so I use this

```
    $("select").delegate("select2:select", "change", function(e) {
```

but it does not work

Comment: how about this => `$(document").on("select2:select", 'select', function(e) {});` if its does not work - Can you add your HTML because this `select2:select` does not look nice to me!

Comment: .....also `.delegate` is a deprecated function since jQuery 3.0 - Do not use that